# Feed list w/ unknown size to neural network

Tags: neural-network, feature-extraction

I want to evolve a neural network for a simple four button game.

In this game there are up to 3 enemies, all of which can shoot multiple rockets.

I have all /(player|rocket)(posision|orientation)/ data.

Every entity experiences gravity towards one central fixed point (no interaction -> no 3 body problem here)

But how can I feed e.g. the (unknown amount of) rockets into the NN?

What's the "best practice" in such a case, or do i have to feature extract
something like the nearest rocket and the nearest enemy?

Comment: Your description is very vague but if I understand you correctly, you can't input "unknown" data. A NN is there to generalize from parameters. To do that, they have to be known. If they're not, you're modeling your problem in a wrong way and have to learn the unknowns instead (classification). Otherwise you have to see for yourself if you can find approximations of your data to train. It's not clear from your description how one would do that (you forgot to explain the actual purpose of the NN).

Comment: The NN should classify the situation into situations where it's 'best' to Fire/Accelerate/Turn. Fitness is expressed by energy (every entity has energy, there's constant cost, shooting costs energy, getting hit costs energy, hitting someone else restores energy)